# GO based Mongo Aggregate Query issue

Tags: mongodb, go

The regular expression query in $in is not working. It works fine in the mongo shell.

Does not work:

```
OpMatch := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"wordname": bson.M{"$in": [...]string{"/^how$/"}}}}
```

Works:

```
OpMatch := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"wordname": bson.M{"$in": [...]string{"how"}}}}
```

Comment: So use what works

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you do regex with mgo. You must use [`bson.RegEx`](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#RegEx). Try this:

`bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"wordname": bson.M{"$in": []bson.RegEx{{"^how$", "i"}}}}}`

Comment: Thanks @Moshe Revah for a very good response. How can I add multiple patterns? for e.g  `{$match : { "wordname":{$in: [/^how$/, /^to$/,/^stop$/, /^neck$/, /^pain$/]}}},`

Comment: Hey Moshe. I solved the question for handling multiple patterns.  Thanks Again. `bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"wordname": bson.M{"$in": []bson.RegEx{ bson.RegEx{"^how$", "i"}},bson.RegEx{"^to$","i"} } }}}`